# just() doesn't work in subscription and flatmap()

Tags: rx-java

The idea is to have Subscription

Subscribes sbscribe to the subscription and when they get one single value, they unsubscribe automatcally.

But somewhy, onComplete() is not called and subscribers continue to receive messages.

Test example:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private final Subject<String, String> mStringSubject = new      
            SerializedSubject<>(PublishSubject.create());


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Handler h = new Handler();

        h.postDelayed(() -> mStringSubject.onNext("Hello1"), 500);
        h.postDelayed(() -> mStringSubject.onNext("Hello2"), 1000);

        mStringSubject.flatMap(Observable::just)
            .subscribe(s -> Log.e("MainActivity", s),
                    Throwable::printStackTrace,
                    () -> Log.e("MainActivity", "Completed"));
    }
}
```

and in the log I see

```
Hello 1
Hello 2
```

But I expect :

```
Hello 1
Completed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing that unsubscribes from `mStringSubject.flatMap(Observable::just)` so the subscriber receives everything `mStringSubject` emits. If you want to make sure every subscriber gets only a single value, apply `take(1)` to the source:

```
Observable<String> o = mStringSubject.flatMap(Observable::just).take(1);

o.subscribe(...)
o.subscribe(...)
```

By the way, `mStringSubject.flatMap(Observable::just)` is just adding overhead and is equivalent to `mStringSubject`.

Comment: But it is still strange for me. In rx source code, just() calls onNext(value) and then unsubscribe(). It should work also. As for me